# Lodash / Javascript - how to find unique keys nested inside objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm trying to go through a large object of data, say of the form:

```
{
 data1: {
     keyA: 'AValue',
     keyB: 'BValue',
     id: 'UniqueID1'
   },
 data2: {
     keyA: 'AValue',
     keyB: 'BValue',
     id: 'UniqueID2'
   },
 data3: {
     keyA: 'AValue',
     keyB: 'BValue',
     id: 'UniqueID1'
   },
 data4: {
     keyA: 'AValue',
     keyB: 'BValue',
     id: 'UniqueID2'
   }
}
```

Is there a method to go through this object and return to me the unique values for 'id'? E.g I would like to end up with the values

```
UniqueID1, UniqueID2,
```

either in an array or an object, it wouldn't matter.
Any help on this would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with plain js using `map()` on `Object.keys()` and `Set` to return array of unique keys.

```js
var data = {"data1":{"keyA":"AValue","keyB":"BValue","id":"UniqueID1"},"data2":{"keyA":"AValue","keyB":"BValue","id":"UniqueID2"},"data3":{"keyA":"AValue","keyB":"BValue","id":"UniqueID1"},"data4":{"keyA":"AValue","keyB":"BValue","id":"UniqueID2"}}

var uniq = [...new Set(Object.keys(data).map(e => data[e].id))]
console.log(uniq)
```

Or with Lodash you can use `map` and then use `uniq`.

```js
var data = {"data1":{"keyA":"AValue","keyB":"BValue","id":"UniqueID1"},"data2":{"keyA":"AValue","keyB":"BValue","id":"UniqueID2"},"data3":{"keyA":"AValue","keyB":"BValue","id":"UniqueID1"},"data4":{"keyA":"AValue","keyB":"BValue","id":"UniqueID2"}}

var uniq = _.uniq(_.map(data, 'id'))
console.log(uniq)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @NenadVracar you can remove `_.values()`, and it would still work

Comment: @ryeballar Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without lodash using Array.reduce and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
const uniques = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc,key) => acc.add(data[key].id), new Set())
console.log(uniques)
```

Answer (score 1):

since you tagged lodash you can do it like this **as array**:

```
var myArray = [
 {
     keyA: 'AValue',
     keyB: 'BValue',
     id: 'UniqueID1'
 },
 {
     keyA: 'AValue',
     keyB: 'BValue',
     id: 'UniqueID2'
 },
 {
     keyA: 'AValue',
     keyB: 'BValue',
     id: 'UniqueID1'
 },
 {
     keyA: 'AValue',
     keyB: 'BValue',
     id: 'UniqueID2'
   }
];

_.map(myArray, 'id');
```

[here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) is the documentation

Comment: yes thanks, and could chain "_.values(data)" to create the array.